# How to plot ocean temperature - gradient fill surrounding single color fill polygon?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a map like top picture that I've posted here. Basically I want the coastline in grey, and the ocean to have a scale of color related to some temperature data I have imported as a csv file
[image]

the data frame looks like so

```
     Longitude   Latitude    Temp     month
1   -64.49677   43.29375    6.760617    M1
2   -64.49677   43.29375    4.384344    M1
3   -64.49677   43.29375    4.384344    M1
4   -64.49677   43.29375    5.736011    M2
5   -64.49677   43.29375    4.004751    M2
6   -64.49677   43.29375    4.004751    M2
7   -64.49677   43.29375    6.139031    M3
8   -64.49677   43.29375    4.358370    M3
9   -64.49677   43.29375    4.358370    M3
10  -64.49677   43.29375    4.931975    M4
11  -64.49677   43.29375    3.564750    M4
12  -64.49677   43.29375    3.564750    M4
13  -64.49677   43.29375    5.227865    M5
14  -64.49677   43.29375    4.619469    M5
15  -64.49677   43.29375    4.619469    M5
sample = structure(list(Longitude = c(-64.4619750976563, -64.46533203125, 
-64.4687118530274, -64.4721221923828, -64.4755630493164, -64.4790267944336
), Latitude = c(42.7215003967285, 42.7790260314941, 42.836483001709, 
42.8938713073731, 42.9511947631836, 43.0084533691406), Temp = c(6.62386226654053, 
7.07512044906616, 7.37884569168091, 7.49466228485107, 7.50688648223877, 
7.53506231307983), month = c("M1", "M1", "M1", "M1", "M1", "M1"
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(month = "M1", .rows = list(
    1:6)), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

So far I have imported a map and created a the following picture, using the following code

```
ggplot(mapoc_temp, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude)) + 
  stat_density2d(aes(fill = ..level..), alpha=0.5, geom="polygon") +
  geom_path(data=canada,aes(x=long, y=lat,group=group), colour="grey50")+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=rev(brewer.pal(7,"Spectral")))+
  coord_sf(xlim=c(-64.5,-62.8), ylim=c(42.7,45), expand = FALSE)
```

[image]

as you can see this map looks nothing like the other picture, and the coastline is colored. Does anyone have any suggestion of how to map some temperature data onto a map?

Comment: `stat_density2d` is estimating the density of datapoints, not showing the temperatures at all. You might be looking for `geom_raster` or `stat_summary_2d`.

Comment: when I use ```geom_raster``` with this code ```ggplot(mapoc_temp, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude)) + 
  geom_raster(data = mapoc_temp, fill = mapoc_temp$Temp) +
  geom_path(data=canada,aes(x=long, y=lat,group=group), colour="grey50")+
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "D")+
  coord_sf(xlim=c(-64.5,-62.8), ylim=c(42.7,45), expand = FALSE)``` I get this error ```Raster pixels are placed at uneven horizontal intervals and will be shifted. Consider using geom_tile() instead.``` But when I use geom_tile I get a similar error message

Comment: and when I try mapping with ```stat_summary_2d``` I get the error message ```Error: stat_summary2d requires the following missing aesthetics: z```

Comment: Have a look at [documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/stat_summary_2d.html), and specifically the examples at the bottom of the page. You'll need to map `z` to `Temp` as the error indicates. The warning you get with `geom_raster` (not an error) already gives you an alternative.

Comment: What do you mean map z to Temp. I don't really understand what z is

Comment: Did you look at the documentation and the examples? First example, first line has `aes(carat, depth, z = price)`. That is mapping `carat` to `x`, `depth` to `y` and `price` to `z`.

Comment: The ggspatial package might help as it will plot a raster in a projected space

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not fully reproducible, but I took some of the data [from your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59951779/how-to-rasterize-and-plot-ocean-temperature-in-ggplot)

I think you can 'safely' ignore the warning from using `geom_raster` and use this with `interpolate = TRUE`

Furthermore, I did not get the warning when plotting a 'complete' raster such as below.

The below shows how to avoid your coast to be showing colors, very simply just drawing the map above your raster, but using `geom_polygon` with a fill. Because you have only provided 6 temperature data points, I created some fake data - depending on the density of your measurements, this will look more or less granular

```r
library(mapdata)
#> Loading required package: maps
library(tidyverse) 

canada <- map_data("worldHires", "Canada")

sample_df <- expand.grid(data.frame(Longitude= seq(-64.5,-62.4,0.1), Latitude= seq(42.7,44.8,0.1)))
sample_df$Temp <- runif(nrow(sample_df))
#requires sf package
ggplot(sample_df, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude)) + 
  geom_raster(aes(fill = Temp, x = Longitude), interpolate = TRUE) +
  geom_polygon(data = canada, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), colour="grey50", fill = 'grey55')+
  coord_sf(xlim=c(-64.5,-62.8), ylim=c(42.7,45))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-01-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is really helpful, but now when I try that code I get the error message that my vector is too large ```Error: cannot allocate vector of size 39.7 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In f(...) :
  Raster pixels are placed at uneven horizontal intervals and will be shifted. Consider using geom_tile() instead.
2: In f(...) :
  Raster pixels are placed at uneven vertical intervals and will be shifted. Consider using geom_tile() instead.``` and it won't map.

Comment: @KristenCyr can you post your exact code please? The one from your plot only

Comment: ```canada <- map_data("worldHires", "Canada")
ggplot(mapoc_temp, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude)) + 
  geom_raster(aes(fill = Temp, x = Longitude), interpolate = TRUE) +
  geom_polygon(data = canada, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), colour="grey50", fill = 'grey55')+
  coord_sf(xlim=c(-64.5,-62.8), ylim=c(42.7,45))```